# Smallest Connected Graph for Given Degree Sequence

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory, degree-sequence

For a given integer sequence $(d_1, d_2,...,d_n)$, a natural question is if such a sequence is  graphical, i.e. is a degree sequence of some graph. According to Erdős–Gallai theorem, A sequence of non-negative integers $d_1\geq\cdots\geq d_n$ can be represented as the degree sequence of a finite simple graph on $n$ vertices if and only if $d_1+\cdots+d_n$ is even and

$\sum^{k}_{i=1}d_i\leq k(k-1)+ \sum^n_{i=k+1} \min(d_i,k)$
holds for $1\leq k\leq n.$

My questions are

(1) If Erdős–Gallai theorem holds, what is the condition that this graph is unique?

(2) If those graphs are not unique, how to find a connected graph with smallest connectivity among them?

Comment: in what sense can you talk about the smallest graph here? All such graphs have the same number of vertices and edges.

Comment: regarding the uniqueness, very few graphs are characterized by their degree sequences. E.g. cubic graphs (all $d_k=3$) on $n$ vertices form a very big family...

Comment: smallest connected can be both smallest vertex connected and smallest edge connected.

Comment: I don't understand. The number of vertices and the number of edges are already GIVEN!

Comment: The total numbers are given, but not the exact graph topologies.

Comment: ok, but what are you minimizing?

Comment: minimize the connectivity

Comment: ok, i edited the question as to make it clear here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A theorem of Hakimi says
that any pair of degree-equivalent graphs can be obtained one
from the other by a sequence of "elementary $2$-switchings"
(probably known under many other names), which involve
the subgraph switch on the subgraph induced
by four vertices, as illustrated in one instance below.

---

[image: GDegSeqs]

---

So whatever you seek to minimize (cf. the comments),
likely it could be pursued by searching for the minimum
via these $2$-switchings.

---

> Hakimi, S. Louis. "On realizability of a set of integers as degrees of the vertices of a linear graph. I." *Journal of the Society for Industrial & Applied Mathematics*. **10**.3 (1962): 496-506.
>
> Hakimi, S. Louis. "On realizability of a set of integers as degrees of the vertices of a linear graph II. Uniqueness." *Journal of the Society for Industrial & Applied Mathematics*. **11**.1 (1963): 135-147.

Comment: @RupeiXu: You are welcome :-). But perhaps the min-connectivity is not easy to find. It is a nice problem you have isolated, as superficially it is not clear if it is polynomial or NPC...